# Flask application with multiple views, how does 'flask run' work in this case?

Tags: python, flask

So I'm coming from the world of spring mvc, and so far Flask has been great.
I've got multiple views/controllers in different python files(this could easily be the wrong approach if so please tell me).

And i want to use the flask command 'run' to try out my controller with postman, is there anyway i can call run on multiple python files at once? it's just this command that has me confused:
**export FLASK_APP=hello.py**

In each controller I also have this line:
app = FLASK(**name**)

is this require?

I've looked into flask blueprints but they seem to be about sharing functionality which I dont really require, would love to know if they were the way forward.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple file is not possible but all the multiple files share the single `app = Flask(__name__)` right ? You can use this app to start the flask run.

```
file1.py => app = Flask(__name__)
file2.py => from file import app
file3.py => from file import app


export FLASK_APP=file1.py
flask run
```

Comment: oh wow thanks, in the python world is it considered better to use a single file for all your controllers? even if they are very different from the perspective of the services they use?

Comment: It depends on your project structure. But runner is expecting as single instance